# Cannot use php to fetch data from mysql to html table, shows Internal Server Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I wrote the php code below to fetch data from mysql to html table, but no matter how I tried, it always show Internal Server Error, could there anyone can help me to take a look at the code?

And I tested the query in mysql, it works, I don't know why when I add it to php, it just crashed.

```
$StartDate = date( 'Y-m-d' strtotime($_POST['StartDate']));
$EndDate = date( 'Y-m-d' strtotime($_POST['EndDate']));

$link = mysql_connect('****', '****', '****');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db(****); 

// Search by date query
$SearchByDate = "
    SELECT Order_Info.OrderID, Order_Info.Date, Client_Info.Manager, Material_Info.MateRefNum,       Order_Info.CustomMateName,
    Order_Info.Quantity, Order_Info.Weight, Order_Info.TechRequire, Order_Info.UniPrice, Order_Info.TotPrice,   Order_Info.OtherNote
    FROM Order_Info, Client_Info, Material_Info
    WHERE Order_Info.MateID = Material_Info.MateID
    AND Order_Info.ClientID = Client_Info.ClientID
    AND Order_Info.Date >  '$StartDate' 
    AND Order_Info.Date < '$EndDate'
    ORDER BY Order_Info.Date DESC;
";

$query = mysql_query($SearchByDate,$link);

echo "<div><table>";
echo "<tr><td>OrderID</td><td>Date</td><td>Client</td><td>Material Number</td><td>Material Name</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Weight</td><td>Technical Requirement</td><td>Unit Price</td><td>Total Price</td><td>Notes</td></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.OrderID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.Date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Client_Info.Manager']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Material_Info.MateRefNum']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_info.CustomMateName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.Quantity']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.Weight']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.TechRequire']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.UniPrice']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.TotPrice']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".row['Order_Info.OtherNote']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? There's a lot of code there and you should have been able to whittle it down to a *much* smaller portion of code without our help.

Comment: "Internal Server Error"?? i think it is nothing do with SQL

Comment: TT I just use dreamwear for doing this,,, may I ask how to debug it? Thank you~~

Comment: which development environment are you in? XAMPP? WAMP? LAMP?

Comment: Er... What are all these environments? I just use dreamwear or notpad and code and upload to server which support php...

Comment: Do other pages work? If don't then it is your server problem. Read more about "Internal Server Error" at http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: What version of PHP? I know that mysql is depricated in the later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your variable must be using symbol '$', but you did not
2. you can use `var_dump($row)` to help you to know how the structure of the array

the code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['OrderID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Manager']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['MateRefNum']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['CustomMateName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Quantity']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Weight']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['TechRequire']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['UniPrice']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['TotPrice']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['OtherNote']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! And I feel shame lost the $... But It still shows Internal server error... Is there anything wrong with the query? T T It makes me so stress..

Comment: Maybe you add a line `die();` after `mysql_select_db(****);`. Could it return the message of 'Connected successfully' ??